# Where should I store global data for my multi-site WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I wrote a plugin for WordPress which has a few user-configurable settings that are stored using WordPress's suggested method.  I know they are saved in the wp_options table, but that is abstracted by the WordPress options API.

Now I'm trying to add a "global override" of the settings that can be configured in the Network Admin section of a multi-site installation.  I found the appropriate hooks to design my settings page, however I can't find any info about where to save the data.

If I save it using the normal options API, then the settings get saved individually for each site.  I'm looking for a place to save them globally for all sites, so the plugin can first look to see if the settings have been globally overridden by the server admin.

I can just write some code to write directly to the wp_options table of one of the sites (for example site #1) or even create my own table.  I know how to do all of these things, but I don't want to do that if there's a preferred way to write mult-site plugins.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Good question. Interested to know the answer. If you don't find a clearly defined way, I would encourage you to submit a ticket to WordPress. As multi-site is relatively new, this may indeed be missing from the core.

Comment: Please repost to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . I think you will get an answer more quickly there.

Comment: ah, didn't know that site existed thanks.  i re-posted here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/where-should-i-store-global-data-for-my-multi-site-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As you know the main deference between developing a single WordPress plugin vs. a multisite plugin is where data is written. According to [this article](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/write-a-plugin-for-wordpress-multi-site) since plugins normally have complete reign over one database, and in some cases the plugins local pages files you must be sure to only call the $wpdb global object instead of a hard-coded reference to a table.

For example, if you need to execute an SQL command on the posts table, then do not use wp_posts as the table name `$post_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts"));`

use this

`$post_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts"));`

Please see the [article](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/write-a-plugin-for-wordpress-multi-site) for further info.